# Why is this function name resolved when passed a class argument?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I came across something odd with how a function name was resolved by the compiler when inside a namespace. Take this example:

```cpp
namespace test {
  class Blah{};

  void good(Blah);
  void bad(int);
}

int main()
{
    good(test::Blah());
    bad(0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compile error `main.cpp:11:5: error: ‘bad’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘test::bad’?`

I expected it to also fail to find `good` as well. Reading though the [name lookup rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) I can't find why this works.

Please explain why `good` is found but `bad` is not. Thank you.

Comment: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)